# Angular 5 Animations : setting 'overlay: hidden' before 'slideUp'

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have this trigger :

```
export const slideInOutTrigger = trigger('slideInOut', [
    state('true', style({
        height: '0',
        opacity: '0',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    })),
    state('false', style({
        height: '*',
        opacity: '1',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    })),
    transition('true => false, 1 => 0', animate('300ms linear')),
    transition('false => true, 0 => 1', animate('300ms linear'))
]);
```

It is used on a reqular Div :

```
<button (click)="collapsed = !collapsed">Trigger</button>
<div [@slideInOut]="collapsed">
    // other content
    <ng-select>..</ng-select> // <-CUSTOM SELECTBOX
</div>
```

Everything works fine, smooth animation.
While sliding up, the content of the Div has to be invisible, so **"overlay: hidden"** is used (Otherwise it looks weird).

**Conflict with Div content :**

**"overlay: hidden"** hinders the custom selectbox to get fully shown.

[image: This is ok]

versus

[image: This is not]

The options of the selectbox get cut when the bottom edge of the Div is reached.

**My question :**
I want to

- set the "overlay: 'hidden'" attribute **temporarily and before** the Div is sliding up.
- after slideDown is complete, the attribute should be
  "overlay: 'visible'" again.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following state-machine:

```
export const slideInOutTrigger = trigger('slideInOut', [
    state('true', style({
        height: '0',
        opacity: '0',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    })),
    state('false', style({
        height: '*',
        opacity: '1',
        overflow: 'visible'
    })),
    transition('true => false', animate('300ms linear')),
    transition('false => true', [
        style({ overflow: 'hidden' }),
        animate('300ms linear')
    ])
]);
```

The key difference being the second parameter of `transition()`, which expects an array of states and animations. The `overflow` CSS property transitions from hidden to not-hidden after a period of 300ms.